# robots.txt and risk associated

Tags: privacy

`robots.txt` is a file that contains path which cannot be crawled by bot most of time search-engine bots like Google bot, etc. It tells search-engine that this directory is private and cannot be crawled by them.

Here is the `robots.txt` file of a site . http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Allow: /
```

Which I simply get by http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/robots.txt.

Is there any risk in using the same?

Secondly, If I trying to search within the website using Google 
by putting in the keyword `site:sppp.rajasthan.gov.in` I get only few results.
So, if `robots.txt` of this particular site doesn't have any restriction, why all the pages within the site are not indexed and shown in Google results?

Comment: The question about google not indexing all your sub-pages is best addressed to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: The second question is completely off-topic here (it isn't about security) and the first question, "is there any risk" is far too broad. What risks are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't make sense what's written in this specific robots.txt, I do not see a security risk in having a robots.txt in general.

The web application / website should be secure enough, even if sensitive directories are revealed by robots.txt as security by obscurity should be avoided at all times.

In other words, even if I as an attacker know all your sensitive locations, I should not be able to download or view any sensitive information.

Comment: @Jeoron The above mentioned robots.txt should allow the search engine to crawl everything on this website as nothing has been disallowed.But then why site:sppp.rajasthan.gov.in results in very fewer results

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia This has nothing to do with it security.

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia robots.txt can't prevent any search engine from doing anything. It's just a guideline for good-mannered engines, and malware can just ignore it.

Comment: @deviantfan I know that.. what I want to know is if a robots.txt has no restrictions, then why a search engine like google(good search engine) hasnt crawled the entire website and indexed the same.Name of the site is http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in   when i do site:sppp.rajasthan.gov.in in google I get very less result

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia Google has no obligation to index every page on the site though. A lot of things could also have happened between google crawling and your retrieval of `robots.txt`. For all we know, the server may serve a different version of the file depending on the user agent.

Comment: @billc.cn could you please elaborate on your answer, if you say that google doesnt have any obligation to what it indexes and what it doesnt then there might be some pre-defined to what google indexes and to what it doesnt... and do you mean to say that google might not have a fresh copy of some of the files of the site..so it showing cached results?